# Location doesn't update

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My location and direction doesn't automatically change when I move my device. Also, it never shows the exact location.

I'm only using `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`. [Here's what I get](https://i.ibb.co/b1NBdPL/Screenshot-20190705-192803-News-Map.jpg)

Comment: Although deprecated, you can use `setOnMyLocationChangedListener()` function of the GoogleMap class.

Comment: @Taslim Oseni I decided not to use because it's deprecated on purpose

Answer (score 0):

One fast approach would be to use `OnLocationChangedListener`, but that's deprecated (sorry :-) lol).

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-methods),

> This interface is deprecated. Use `com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi` instead.
>   FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power
>   usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the
>   MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example
>   example code, or the [Location Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location).

**Therefore, the `FusedLocationProviderAPI` is your best bet. You can follow the link in the documentation snippet.**

I hope this helps. Merry coding!